# Mysql Regex query find first latter and begins with given work/character

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have pre-build application and in this application, there are some MySQL queries which are executing Regex queries. And I'm trying to use those queries other place. When I'm using same Regex query other place then those are not working.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE field_name REGEXP '^[[:<:]]e[^[:space:]]* k.*'
```

When I'm executing this query in MySQL then getting this message:-

```
#3685 - Illegal argument to a regular expression.
```

I'm stuck here. Please help me to resolve issue.

**Edited:-**
[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) as you told to use `\\b` if I'm using `[[:<:]]` or `[[:>:]]`. But query is not providing any result. Below is the query which I'm executing:-

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE field_name REGEXP "\\b'what that'\\b"
```

Comment: This part: `[:<:]` makes the regular expression invalid. I don't know what you are trying to do, you can test other variations of that part.

Comment: @forpas yes `[:<:]` was invalid so corrected this to `[[:<:]]`

Comment: You are using MySQL 8, right? Use `REGEXP '^e\\S* k'`. Wherever you have `[[:<:]]` or `[[:>:]]`, replace with `\\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please check my question.

Comment: Why did you use `REGEXP "\\b'what that'\\b"`?  I suggested  `REGEXP '\\bwhat that\\b'`. But now, you say it is MySQL 5.6, your `[[:<:]]text[[:>:]]` should work. Please provide sample record you want to be returned with this regexp query.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is not working

Comment: It does work since it finds `it is what that here` and does not find a match in `wwhat that`. But you seem to want `a.*b|b.*a` pattern, `what.*that|that.*what`

Comment: Does that work now?

Comment: Yes I found solution. Basically on my local system I have 8.0 and on production server I have 5.7. So I did some research and find solution for both. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Does it mean the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020006/mysql-regex-query-find-first-latter-and-begins-with-given-work-character?noredirect=1#comment100580887_57020006 comment works for you? `REGEXP '\\bwhat that\\b'` and `[[:<:]]text[[:>:]]`?